# Sharepoint webpart not able to get the auth token from teams

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, web-parts, microsoft-teams-js

I have a teams tab app  in which I have a component in which I have the following code.

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { ITokenIssuer } from 
"../../interfaces/tokenIssuer/ITokenIssuer";
class TeamsTokenIssuer implements ITokenIssuer {
constructor(context:WebPartContext) {
    this.initializeMicrosoftTeamsApp(context);
}

private initializeMicrosoftTeamsApp = async (context:WebPartContext) => {
    console.log("initialize teams app");
    console.log(context);
    await context.sdks.microsoftTeams?.teamsJs.app.initialize();
}
async getAccessToken(context: WebPartContext): Promise<string> {
    microsoftTeams
    console.log("user",await context.sdks.microsoftTeams?.teamsJs.authentication.getUser());
    let accessToken: string | undefined = "";
    try {

        accessToken = await context.sdks.microsoftTeams?.teamsJs.authentication.getAuthToken();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    if(!accessToken) return "";
    return accessToken;
}
}

export default TeamsTokenIssuer;
```

chunk.spfx-core-teamsenv-teamsJs-v2_none_6e125c783faf9954e07e.js:1  Uncaught (in promise) Error: App does not have the required permissions for this operation
My permissions for the app are -
MicrosoftGraph email openid offline access profile user.read
Permissions in my manifest.json file

```
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
```

I have deployed this app in sharepoint and the app is hosted on a sharepoint domain

Comment: You are using the getAuthToken method from the authentication namespace of the teamsJs object to get an access token. This method requires that the app has the necessary permissions to get an auth token. You may want to check the app's permissions and make sure that it has been granted the necessary permissions to perform this operation. The required for this operation include User.Read, email, openid, profile, and offline_access. These permissions should be included in the webApplicationInfo section of your app's manifest file.

Comment: "webApplicationInfo": {
"id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
"applicationPermissions": [
"User.Read",
"email",
"openid",
"profile",
"offline_access"
]
}